# Emulate document locking in Lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, agents, background-agents

In my Lotus Notes Application, when a user clicks an action, the action will call a run-on-server agent that will process the current document. The invoked agents sometimes doesn't run (which I think because of the concurrent agent limit of the server). This is why every 5 minutes there is a maintenance agent that runs to processed documents that are not processed by the invoked agents. The problem is, sometimes, a document is SIMULTANEOUSLY processed by these 2 agents, producing unacceptable results.

Is there a way I can emulate the document locking, such that documents can only be processed by one agent at a time? I don't like to use the native document locking because problems with the business rules might arise. I tried tagging the documents when one of the agents process it, then clears the flag after it is done. But the problem here is that there will still be a chance that the agents get hold of the document reference AT THE SAME TIME (due to the delay of saving the document, maybe).

Please help me. Thanks! :D

Comment: It sounds like you might want to rethink your design, why not execute the code directly on the client when the user clicks the button? 
If you say that it takes too long, perhaps you can optimize your code instead? Use a profiler and see where the slowness is. That way you avoid the whole thing. I never use run-on-server agents to process a document currently being displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that is not hard. Create a locking database where you have locking documents. They really only need to contain the UNID of the document being locked.

When your agents start processing a document, check if a locking document exists. If not, create one.
If there is one, either wait or skip the document for now.
After the document is done processing, delete the locking document.

This is trivial. Back when we were still on Notes/Domino 5, I even wrote a simple class to handle document locking in one of my application. The code below is referencing some functions and variables from another script library, but you get the idea. I am sure you can easily modify the code to work for you.

```
Option Public
Option Declare
Use "Functions.Globals"


Class DocumentLock
    Private lockdb As NotesDatabase
    Private lockview As NotesView
    Private lockdoc As NotesDocument
    Private lockservername As String
    Private lockdbname As String
    Private lnpdoc As NotesDocument ' Document to lock/unlock

    Public Sub New(doc As NotesDocument)
        me.lockservername = globals.GetValue("LockServer")
        me.lockdbname = AppHomeDir + globals.GetValue("LockDBname")
        If me.lockdb Is Nothing Then
            Set me.lockdb = New NotesDatabase(me.lockservername, me.lockdbname)
        End If
        Set me.lockview = me.lockdb.GetView("LockedDocs")
        Call me.lockview.Refresh()
        Set me.lnpdoc = doc
    End Sub

    Public Sub LockMe()
        Set me.lockdoc = New NotesDocument(me.lockdb)       
        me.lockdoc.Form="Locked"
        me.lockdoc.LockUNID=me.lnpdoc.UniversalID
        me.lockdoc.LockUser= globalcurrentusername 
        me.lockdoc.LockTime=Str(Now())
        me.lockdoc.ClaimNumber = me.lnpdoc.GetItemValue("ClaimNumber")(0)
        me.lockdoc.DocumentForm = me.lnpdoc.GetItemValue("Form")(0)
        Call me.lockdoc.Save(True,True)
    End Sub

    Public Sub UnlockMe()
        Call me.lockview.Refresh()
        Set me.lockdoc = me.lockview.GetDocumentByKey(me.lnpdoc.UniversalID)
        If Not me.lockdoc Is Nothing Then
            Call me.lockdoc.Remove(True)
            Call me.lockview.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function IsLocked(flagShowInfo As Boolean) As Boolean
        Call lockview.Refresh()
        Set me.lockdoc = me.lockview.GetDocumentByKey(me.lnpdoc.UniversalID)
        If me.lockdoc Is Nothing Then
            me.IsLocked = False
        Else
            me.IsLocked = True
            If flagShowInfo = True Then
                MsgBox "Document locked " & locktext & "." & Chr$(13) & "Please wait a while and try again.."
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function LockText() As String
        LockText = "by " & LockUserName() & " at " & me.lockdoc.LockTime(0) 
    End Function

    Public Function LockUserName() As String
        Dim lockedby As String
        lockedby = me.lockdoc.LockUser(0)
        If lockedby = globalcurrentusername Then
            LockUserName = "you"
        Else
            LockUserName = lockedby
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```